# SQL Summarizing the number of days in each month from a data set

Tags: sql, date, summary

I have a table that looks like this and I want to be able to summarize by ReportID the following.  There should be one listing for a ReportID and type and the number of days in each month under the listed months.   I don't want to have to figure out the begin and end date for the dataset, it should be automatic.

[[image: Results1]

.

[[image: Sample Table2]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: Barb Reinhardt, try new query after mark EDIT

Comment: jarih:   I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `Sql server` and you need to calculate number of days between Startdate and EndDate  *within ReportId* than you use `window function sum` and `datetime function datediff` (to count days):

```
select Type,ReportID,sum(datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate))
over (partition by ReportId order by StartDate rows unbounded preceding)count_days_rep 
from Table
```

Or if you need to summarize count days *within ReportId and Type:*

```
select Type,ReportID,sum(datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate))
over (partition by ReportId,Type  order by StartDate rows unbounded preceding) count_days_rep_type
from Table
```

EDIT:

At first, we counting days for *startdate* and *enddate* and then using `Cross apply` to get day's count in one column.
After that just `summing values` for each *ReportId,Type*:
(write comments):

```
--counting days for each month group by ReportId,Type
select ReportId,Type,Tab.month_num,
sum(Tab.count_days)count_days
from
(
select *, 

--startdate: if startdate's month=enddate's month then difference between days 
--ELSE count report days for startdate (counting days from this date to the end of the month)

case when datepart(month,StartDate)=datepart(month,EndDate) then datediff(dd,StartDate,EndDate)+1 
else datepart(dd,EOMONTH(StartDate))-datepart(dd,StartDate)+1 end CountStartDays,
--stardate's month
datename(month,StartDate)MonthStartDate,


--enddate: if startdate's month=enddate's month then 0 (because this value taken into account already in CountStartDays) ELSE count report days for enddate 
--(counting days from the begginning of enddate's month till date)

 case when datepart(month,StartDate)=datepart(month,EndDate) then 0 else datepart(dd,EndDate) end CountEndDays,
--enddate's month
datename(month,EndDate)MonthEndDate
from Table

)y

CROSS APPLY

(values  (MonthStartDate,CountStartDays),
         (MonthEndDate, CountEndDays)  ) Tab (month_num,count_days)

group by Type,ReportId,Tab.month_num
```

I hope you can appreciate my efforts.

Comment: That gets me part of they way.   Instead of the total number of days, I need to know the number of days in each month.

Comment: Barb Reinhardt, have written query (after statement EDIT)

Comment: Barb Reinhardt, do you try query?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but I'm getting ReportID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.   I've tried putting it a couple of places, but have not used CROSS APPLY Before.

Comment: This query is working. It's working on my database. You have described error, but how it can be,if ReportId is in the groupby sentence.check it please.

Comment: Do you add this :                                 
group by Type,ReportId,Tab.month_num

Comment: Check this:                    CROSS APPLY

(values  (MonthStartDate,CountStartDays),
         (MonthEndDate, CountEndDays)  ) Tab (month_num,count_days)
     
group by Type,ReportId,Tab.month_num